# Paymill OpenSSL and Heroku

Tags: heroku, paymill

I am building a Rails 3.2.9 app. In this app I am using the Ruby gem Paymill. All works fine on local Mac but on Heroku I get this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname was not match with the server certificate)
```

What can be wrong?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question, per se, but Rails 3.2.10 is out now with a security fix, so you'll want to update it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it buy updating the Ruby version I use on Heroku by adding this to my gem file:

*ruby "1.9.3"*

Comment: I can confirm that! Thank you very much, this saved me a lot of time. <3